# How to separate 0's and 1's in text document after 50 consecutive values by using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have black and white image and i read that image in **MATLAB**. I
    have save my image file in binary as **0's** and **1's** by using **dlmwrite**
    command in **MATLAB.**

Now i want to implement an Algorithm in which i want to get first **50**
    values in first row and then next 50 values in second row and third
    **50** values in next row and so on. What should be the code for it. I
    have written the code and getting an error in logic.

```
      a= 100;
      b= 100;

         for j= 0:length(a)

              for i= 0:length(b)

                   dlmwrite('rd.txt','rd[i,j]','delimiter','b','c');

               end

          end
```

I need result like this

00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 //  50 bits per line
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 //  50 bits per line
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 //  50 bits per line
.
.
So on

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have your 0s and 1s in an array, and want to somehow output them with a given column width. If that is the case, [`reshape`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) can generally do what I believe you want, except that your data may not be evenly divisible by the width of your columns, i.e., 50. One way would be to first pad the data such that it is, e.g.

```matlab
data = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
colwidth = 6;

% padding data to fit evenly in full rows
data = [data, repmat(' ', 1, colwidth-mod(numel(a), colwidth))];

% reshaping into columns of given width
reshape(data, colwidth, [])'
```

This will give you

```matlab
  5×6 char array

    'abcdef'
    'ghijkl'
    'mnopqr'
    'stuvwx'
    'yz    '
```

Or you can get the parts separately:

```matlab
reshape(data(1:end-mod(numel(data), colwidth)), colwidth, [])'
data(end-mod(numel(data), colwidth)+1:end)
```

giving you

```matlab
ans =

  4×6 char array

    'abcdef'
    'ghijkl'
    'mnopqr'
    'stuvwx'


ans =

    'yz'
```

Comment: I have the data 0's and 1's in text document. Can i use the padding technique for text file?

Comment: Sure, you can get your 0s and 1s from a text file first, e.g. using [textscan](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html): `fid = fopen('data.txt'); data = textscan(fid, '%s'); fclose(fid);` will give you a cell of that file's contents. If your text file has just 0s and 1s, no line breaks, then `data{1}` will contain your data, and you can apply the above method.